# Custom Membership Provider with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, custom-membershipprovider

I have a MVC web application that I am using my own membership provider. I have implemented the Entity Framework with POCO’s, repositories, and a unit of work to both the MVC app and the Custom Membership Provider.

I am finding that when the data changes outside of the entity created in the membership provider, the data is not updated. The system works fine when the entities are short lived in a web request, but the membership provider is started with the web application and is not disposed like a controller.

I have read every post I could find and have not found how to overcome this limitation of Entity Framework. Do I have to resort to the old ADO code to get the latest data from the database?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have overrided WebSecurity and other Microsoft Membership Provider classes at the right way. For Security reasons and the Architecture of Entity Framework, may not happen appropriate coordination among those. A good example for implementing sample membership provider with Entity Framework and Asp.net Membership provider can be found at The [nuget gallery](https://nuget.org/packages/CodeFirstMembershipProviderSharp). I wish to be useful for you.